# How to use Imagemagick to remove color profile without removing EXIF data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick, exif, color-profile

Image file in my server are processed using imagemagick. Sometimes I get files with color profiles from users and i use -strip to remove them before uploading the images to storage. Using -strip also removed EXIF data from the images. I'm interested to know if there is a way to only remove color profiles and not exif info regarding geo location and camera settings?

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
convert +profile '!exif,*' in.jpg out.jpg
```

According to the [ImageMagick docu](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile) you can use +profile to remove the indicated profile. ImageMagick uses standard filename globbing, so wildcard expressions can be used to exclude specific profiles.

So `+profile "!exif,*".` will remove all profiles from the image except for the EXIF profile.

Comment: Consider adding further explanation of why this could be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the +profile flag will work for stripping the colour profiles.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile